# how to handle ejs with ajax request node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, ejs

Let's consider that I have test route that render my index file.
inside index there is table that show my json file which cames form server using `ejs` compilation.now every thing seems good but there is problem here.
I call this index file with `ajax GET` request when the result comes `ejs` compilation comes with error and just my `josn` file has gotten form server so how can I compile ejs file and then got the result with ajax.
So how can I compile ejs first and after that html result send to client?
here is my server side code :

```
var my_json = {
   username : "sample"
   password : "sample2"
   id : 3
}
app.route('/test').get(function(req,res){
     res.render('index',{data : myjson });
});
```

And here is my `index.ejs` file

```
<table id="scoreboard" class="table table-bordered tableSorter">
        <thead>
        <tr class="info">
            <th>username</th>
            <th>password</th>
            <th>id</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <td><%- data.username %> </td>
           <td><%- data.password %> </td>
           <td><%- data.id %> </td>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is my js file :

```
$.ajax({
      url : '/test',
      type : 'GET',
      success : function(html){
             ///I want this html comes after ejs compilation process
             $("#main").html(html);
      },
      error : function(err){
          if(err)throw err;
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check your route work in browser and after that you should ask this question,

just change the render line to this and every thing works fine :

`res.render('index',{ data : my_json });`